# How to add default photo in database using servlet?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, file-upload

How to add a default photo in the database if the user has not uploaded any photo manually?

I'm using this code to handle user-uploaded photos:

```
InputStream inputStream = null;

// obtains the upload file part in this multipart request
Part filePart = request.getPart("photo");

if (filePart != null) {
    // prints out some information for debugging
    System.out.println(filePart.getName());
    System.out.println(filePart.getSize());
    System.out.println(filePart.getContentType());

    // obtains input stream of the upload file
    inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
}

try
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/busbooking","user","password");
    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `busbooking`.`users` (`username`, `Full_name`, `email`, `password`, `Mob_no`, `DOB`, `address`, `Gender`, `Usertype`, `Agency_name`, `Photo`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    ps.setString(1, username);
    ps.setString(2, FullName);
    ps.setString(3, email);
    ps.setString(4, passwd);
    ps.setString(5, mobile);
    ps.setString(6, dob);
    ps.setString(7, address);
    ps.setString(8, gender);
    ps.setString(9, Usertype);
    ps.setString(10, AgencyName);
    if (inputStream != null) {
        // fetches input stream of the upload file for the blob column
        ps.setBlob(11, inputStream);
    }
    ps.executeUpdate();   

    out.println("<script>alert('Registration Successful');</script>");
    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("LoginPage1.jsp");
    rd.include(request, response);

    ps.close();
    con.close();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to make it simpler and easier to understand. I also did some formatting to your code to look a bit better, but it should be simplified even more to be quick & easy to gasp. You can remove unimportant lines from it, like the calls to `ps.setString` so that others can focus on the essential parts. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can either have a default image in your database table for your *Photo* column or if the user does not upload an image, the create an input stream from some default image photo on server with :

```
  File initialFile = new File("src/main/resources/sample.txt");
  InputStream targetStream = new FileInputStream(initialFile);
```

*Source of the example*: 
http://www.baeldung.com/convert-file-to-input-stream

Comment: Although in MySql Blob columns cannot have a default value. So this is not an option for you.

Comment: Can you post the code with what you have exactly tried?